# How to achieve filter by price range in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular6

I have an E-Commerce Site of watches ranging from $20 to $60 price.The project is devloped in Angular 6 and Firebase as database. I want to filter the products by price range i.e Under 20, 20 -30, 30 - 40 and so on...

Following are the files used for price filter
1. product-fliter.component.html

```
<div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
        [class.active]="!price" routerLink="/">
          All Price
        </a>
        <a *ngFor="let p of price$ | async" 
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
        routerLink="/" [queryParams]="{ price : p.key}"
        [class.active]="price === p.key">     
              {{p.name}}
        </a>
</div>
```

2. product-fliter.component.ts

```
price$;
  @Input('price') price;

constructor(priceService: PriceService) { 
    this.price$ = priceService.getPrice();
  }
```

3. price.service.ts

```
itemRef : any;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getPrice() {
    this.itemRef =  this.db.list('/price').snapshotChanges().pipe
    (map(changes => { return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, 
    ...c.payload.val() }));
    }));
    return this.itemRef;  
  }
```

4. home.component.ts
   (This is where I'am applying fliter logic)

```
private populateProducts() { 
    this.productService.getAll().subscribe(products => {
      this.products = products;

      this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {

          if(params.get('price') || this.price) {
          this.price= params.get('price');
          this.applyFilterPrice();
        } 
      });
    }); 
  }
```

Following are the images for reference
[image: Firebase Price Range]
[image: Products View on Site]
I want the products to be filtered by their price. Any changes or any modifications would be well and good. I would like to know the working of Price Range Slider and its code in Angular 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
private populateProducts() { 
    this.productService.getAll().subscribe(products => {

      // here is where you can filter
      this.products = products.filter(product => {
         return product.price >= this.minimumPrice
             && product.price <= this.maximumPrice
       });

      this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {

          // Can you clarify why you use this if conditional ?
          if(params.get('price') || this.price) {
          this.price= params.get('price');
          this.applyFilterPrice();
        } 
      });
    }); 
  }
```

I hope this was helpful in your case, but be advised that doing this will only filter the products on the front-end, you still have all the products loaded from firebase.

Comment: The line where you asked for clarification is the silly mistake I found...Well I'll try the code as suggested by you... Thanks

Comment: You can also move the `filter` to the observable before you subscribe.

Comment: @Pranav as @Phix you can actually filter it using the `.filter` rxjs pipe operator, but better still is to filter using firebase query, like this:

```

db.list('/products').orderByValue('price').startAt(minimumPrice).endAt(maximumPrice)

```

I am not 100% this will work, as I did not use firebase rtdb as my main database since firestore came out, but I think it should.

Comment: How to filter by firebase query?

Comment: Well now the filtering is working perfectly. Now the question is how to sort elements in particular order using firebase query. Like I want to sort the elements as: All Price, Under 20, 20 -30, 30 - 40... Above 60.. Any suggestions?